# How to make this background lighting effect in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if someone here knows how to create these "background lighting" effects? Like this one on tailindcss.com:

[image]

Here is my attempt:

```css
.wrap {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .9;
}
.lighting {
  margin-left: 500px;
  height: 20vh;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  filter: blur(15px);
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="lighting"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you inspected the code of tailwind's website to see how they do it?

Comment: They don't create the effect with CSS. Instead, it's a [background image](https://tailwindcss.com/_next/static/media/hero-dark@90.a7a063e8f9d179fbd72b0b735c5797b7.jpg).

Comment: Alright, emulation is another medium is fair game.

Comment: You can recreate it with craftul use of multiple `background-image` layers: a repeating grid square image, and 2 or 3 _subtle_ radial or conic gradients.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a [similar effect with this tool](https://fffuel.co/bbblurry/) and then use the SVG in your code :

[image]

Just set your shapes positions, sizes and color and download the generated SVG. Very useful !

Answer (score -1):

The exact style that website uses is a mix of two `background-image` styles. The first one is the gradient, the second is the checker pattern:

```
.index_beams__3fKa4 {
    background-image: url(/_next/static/media/hero@75.4dea7abe609fc522c039fba7662ceea2.jpg);
    background-size: 150rem;
}

.bg-grid-slate-900\/\[0\.04\] {
     background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 32 32' width='32' height='32' fill='none' stroke='rgb(15 23 42 / 0.04)'%3e%3cpath d='M0 .5H31.5V32'/%3e%3c/svg%3e);
}
```